# Is iTextSharp/itext7 thread-safe?

Tags: itext, itext7

We are currently using iTextSharp, version 5.5.13. Given that there is a notice that engineers are here on StackOverflow answering questions, riddle me this - is iTextSharp thread-safe? If iTextSharp 5.5 isn't safe, is iText7 thread-safe?

I can work to finding a MVP to prove it out but was hoping to hear from an engineer if this was a design-wise thought and its built into the framework.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you planning to have multiple threads operating on different pdfs or on the same one? Obviously multiple threads writing to the same document likely will fail while multiple threads operating on distinct documents will likely work (given enough memory).

Comment: @mkl I am looking to create multiple documents in parallel.

Comment: If you keep the documents you create in parallel separated, there shouldn't be a problem as long as you have sufficient resources, in particular memory.

Comment: FYI: mkl is not an iText engineer but he's one of our most valued users and his knowledge and experience with iText and with the PDF standard is on par with even the most senior engineers at iText Software.